# Migrate objects and fields using SublimeApex

Tags: migration, sublime

Using the [Salesforce IDE for Sublime Text 3 (SublimeApex)](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Salesforce%20IDE) to interact with Salesforce data I've come across a couple questions I'm hoping to find help with.

Can I migrate custom objects and/or fields from my sandbox into my production environment? Is it something I have to manually setup in the package.xml or is it something even possible with this tool?

Most of the help I can find about migrating object data mentions MavensMate or the Force.com Migration tool but before I look into those options I really want to understand the process and determine if the tool I'm currently using is capable for performing such a task.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like that supports moving objects. I use MavensMate to do this all the time. They have a nice bootstrapped interface where you can simply choose the objects and such from one org, build the package.xml automatically, and then do your deploy to any other org. Very very easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Working with the developer @Hao Liu I'm posting this response because his english is not as good. But I want to thank him for his commitment to this great Sublime Text plugin and contribution to the Salesforce developers community

## 1. Set up SublimeApex

To start, once you install [SublimeApex](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Salesforce%20IDE) from [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) and restart Sublime Text, you first need to setup your user settings (this will establish your authentication to for any environment you wish to connect to):

[image: Setup User Settings]

Project examples, you can setup as many as you want (Production, Sandbox, Developer environment, etc)

```
"projects":
{
    "Production":
    {
        "allowed_packages":
        [
        ],
        "default": false,
        "login_url": "https://login.salesforce.com",
        "password": "********",
        "production": "https://login.salesforce.com",
        "sandbox": "https://test.salesforce.com",
        "security_token": "Ucv1d984sdfbbg64py",
        "username": "email@company.com"
    },
    "Sandbox":  <<---- These cannot be the same, i.e. "Project-Name"
    {
        "allowed_packages":
        [
        ],
        "default": true,
        "login_url": "https://test.salesforce.com",
        "password": "********",
        "security_token": "h94jhjhyn98bvtre7wg4ewtrh",
        "username": "email@company.com.dev"
    }
},
"workspace": "C:/projects/salesforce"
```

> **NOTE:** Projects are essentially like your environments as you'll see played out here

If you switch to any of these projects then a folder with a `.config` folder will appear in your workspace for authentication purposes

[image]
[image]

> **NOTE:** you **can** create as many *or as little* projects from these connections as you would like (each with their own timestamp by default).

## 2. Fetch your project's or environment's package

Next, simply add a new project which will fetch the environment from your *active* project (in this case, Sandbox)

[image]

This will build a default `package.xml` that will package your active environment into a `.zip` and then unpack the contents into the projects workspace or default workspace if there is not one declared for that project in your settings. In Sublime you should see the new folder like this.

[image]

## 3. Create a custom package

For this example we want to include things like **Custom Objects** so that they can be used for deployment to other environments as well. So I need to make a separate *custom* package for this environment, do so by either of the following:

1. right-clicking on the sandbox folder, `SublimeApex > Create Package.xml`
   [image]

**--------------- OR ---------------**

2. copy the current `package.xml` and move to the root of your project directory *(preferred)*

> **TIP:** *Where ever your custom `package.xml` file is when you **retrieve** it is where the fetched package will be*

#### Setup your custom package.xml

Since, for this example, we want Custom Objects we need to include the following:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

Then **save** right-click anywhere in the file (make sure the correct environment/project is still active), and select **SublimeApex > Retrieve Package.xml**

[image]

Once your package has been fetched you should see a new folder `project-name-timestamp], for this example I got`Sandbox-201412171532`

[image: Custom Package with timestamp]

## 4. Deploy Contents

While in a file or by clicking any folder contents within the sidebar, select `SublimeApex > Deploy to Server`

[image]

> **BONUS:** If you curious about what **metadata you can fetch** here's [the documentation page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_api_meta250/Content/file_based.htm)

Answer (score 1):

@Xtremefaith, sorry, I can't add comment below your post.

I like scriptly deployment and always use ant to deploy, generally, I will use eclipse to build my `package.xml` and deploy it by `SublimeApex`, however, building the `package.xml` by UI is very slowly, sometimes, I just want to deploy lots of components and I can directly write the `package.xml` without UI, therefore, in order to improve the efficiency on writing my `package.xml`,  I made lots of improvement work on how to build package.xml more quickly.

If you are familiar with ant deployment, I think below demo is very helpful for you.

I have posted [demo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xjsender/SublimeApexScreenshot/master/BuildPackageXML.gif) to show how to deploy custom fields or something else by [SublimeApex](https://github.com/xjsender/SublimeApex), this demo file is more than 19.5M, when you are opening it, please be patiently.

Comment: Question, so are you just making an unmanaged package and deploying it? And if so is that something that can just be uninstalled by an admin in Salesforce. I'm not familiar with creating packages yet and not sure if this is a saleforce package or just a coincidence because the file is called `package.xml`

Comment: I've been testing MM to see how it works and basically it comes with a GUI but essentially does the same thing, it builds a `package.xml` although neither one seem to fetch all *CustomObjects* when using the `*` wildcard, you have to manually add each `<member>` which kinda stinks :(